# Line breaks based on text length, preserving custom HTML markup

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Maybe missed it, but haven't found a regex (or other way) that accomplishes what I'm trying to do succinctly.

I'm generating long character strings which contain custom HTML tags, which will be displayed as HTML. I'm generating the two strings separately, which have text of the same length and need to maintain character alignment, but each have their own unique markup. E.g. (though will be much longer):

`xxxxx<mytag>nnnn</mytag>xxxx`

`<mytag2>xxxxx</mytag2>nnnn<mytag3>xxxx</mytag3>`

I want to break them into shorter strings (e.g. of 80 characters), so that the alignment is maintained. Obviously, since the markup is different, I can't simply split by character count. **I also need to maintain the HTML tags.**

Ultimately, they will be displayed as an alignment, with one string above the other. I'm open to other ways of doing this, but need to maintain pointer events (custom tags will parse into spans which display tooltips on mouseover). A solution at the string level would be ideal, as the functionality would be useful beyond this single HTML element. I'm working with AngularJS, and the function runs every keystroke, so can't be too intensive.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. You use the word alignment in odd ways. Aligned visually after being rendered by a browser or aligned in your editor? What does "displayed as an alignment" mean?

Comment: Example of input and expected output might clear things

Comment: the function in the answers captures the spirit of what I'm trying to do, but a loop that runs every keystroke will run into problems with large strings. I'm working with DNA, where the individual letters of one string (i.e. A, C, G, T) have a complementary letter in the other string, so alignment in this context means preserving each complementary nucleotide (i.e. letter and its partner)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a regex would be useful in this case.

I have chosen the basic function-walkthrough method, which works pretty well here:

```
function splitByLength(str, length) {
    var lines = [];
    var isInTag = false;
    var start = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var tagLength = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == "<") {
            isInTag = true;
        }

        if (!isInTag) {
            count++;
        } else {
            tagLength++;
        }

        if (count >= length) {
            lines.push(str.substr(start, count+tagLength));
            start = count+tagLength;
            count = 0;
            tagLength = 0;
        }

        if (str[i] == ">") {
            isInTag = false;
        }
    }

    lines.push(str.substr(start));

    return lines;
}
```

Examples:

```
splitByLength("xxxxx<mytag>nnnn</mytag>xxxx", 10)
>>> ["xxxxx<mytag>nnnn</mytag>x", "xxx"]

splitByLength("<mytag2>xxxxx</mytag2>nnnn<mytag3>xxxx</mytag3>", 10)
>>> ["<mytag2>xxxxx</mytag2>nnnn<mytag3>x", "xxx</mytag3>"]
```

Comment: bit late... just noting the reason I'm not accepting this is it's too slow for strings with lengths of several thousand characters. I had been using a traversing function like this and ran into problems